# 2004 Hyundai Sonata V6 Stalled wont start drains battery

Tags: hyundai, cranks-wont-run, sonata

I have a 2004 hyundai sonata that will not start. We have replaced the camshaft sensor, fuel pump, crankshaft sensor, the spark plugs get spark. Car will start but will not turnover, we know the battery is bad but even when attempting to jump the battery it does not start, when it stalled the check engine light came on but the battery drained pretty quickly after that. The fuel injector sensor works fine. Starter checked out as good. I don't want to get a new battery if whatever is wrong with the car will make that battery go bad. No codes are being thrown. I'm at a lost of what to do. Help Please

Comment: You say the car will start.  How did you start it to know it starts?

Comment: Do you hear any relays clicking when you try to start the engine?

Comment: ok it will crank  as normal but will not turn over and when the battery is dead there is clicking, it has not started since it stalled last week

Comment: First get a known good battery, even if you have to borrow one. Hyundai's like a good power source and will go crazy when they don't have one. When you have it turning over well, shoot some carb or brake cleaner down the intake, then crank the engine again. If it fires, even for a brief bit, the problem is fuel related.

Comment: Could you clarify what is happening? Since you description seem contradictory. Started = engine running off fuel.  Turnover = engine turning, but not powered by fuel.   Crank = engine turning using starter motor, but not powered by fuel

Comment: Latricia, crank and turn over means the starter will turn the engine. Start means the engine will run. So an engine that cranks with no start means that the starter turns the engine over, but it won't start (run). If you get to understand these terms it would be helpful to us to diagnose. I believe you're description means you have a crank, no start condition.

Comment: A bad battery can drain all the power from the jump, preventing it from being used during a start. Like Paulster2 said, borrow a battery if you have to. If the battery still drains after getting it started, you might have a bad alternator. A bad charging circuit is possible, but less likely and more expensive.